# Extend Parse SDK Object in TypeScript

Tags: parse-platform, typescript, angular

In order to define easy getters and setters for Parse objects in angular2, I want to extend Parse.Object like so:

```
const Parse = require('parse').Parse;

export class Test extends Parse.Object {

    constructor() {
        super('Test');
    }

    get items():Array<string> {
        return super.get('items');
    }

    set items(value:Array<string>) {
        super.set('items', value);
    }
}

Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Test', Test);
```

However, I get the following error:

`error TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.`